# What to exclude from a gated build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am working on a Windows Forms application and we have a gated check-in environment set up. Currently we are building the entire workspace on every check-in, with just a few of exceptions that are cloaked in the gated build. We would like to optimize the gated build so it runs faster and for this I am looking into what can be generally excluded from the gated build. We can then cloak these folders so changes inside these folders don't trigger a new build. What would be generally speaking a good list of resources, files, types etc. that could be excluded from the build in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

We typically create gated builds for each of our solution folders which build the code and then run our unit tests.